# Android - after configuring a new AVD for the Nook tablet, when running it, I get error

Tags: android

I added two emulators for the Nook device (from Barnes and Noble) which runs the Android operating system.

After configuring it, I tried to run it, and I got this runtime error almost immediately after choosing that AVD to run:

```
[2013-01-07 16:59:15 - Emulator] Failed to allocate memory: 8
[2013-01-07 16:59:15 - Emulator] 
[2013-01-07 16:59:15 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2013-01-07 16:59:15 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Would anyone know why this happened and what I can do to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: Get more RAM? You're running out of memory it seems, since the AVD can't allocate enough.

Comment: @A--C how much ram does that AVD need?

Comment: Actually I just changed the needs of that avd from 1024 to 512 and it seems to be attempting to work :) If you want to post this as an answer I will accept since it was your idea to mess with RAM. Thank you!

Comment: Actually the avd seems to be hanging and just remains dark for few minutes now :) LOL ...debugging that now.

Comment: I'd say wait for a few minutes, emulators are crazy slow sometimes. If that fails, run the emulator from the command line, that way you see all log output. Also, here's my [configuration](http://i.imgur.com/jFCkC.png) for one of my emulators. I'm on a machine with ~3.3GB usable.

Comment: btw, there was a VM heap setting.  I left it at 64. Would another setting for it be better with the 512Ram I gave it?

Comment: I use 32. The heap has to do with the actual Dalvik vm if I'm not mistaken, so it shouldn't affect anything besides how much memory apps (apks) can use while running.

Comment: Cant get it to work....it does not crash, but it just hangs on a black screen for 10+ minutes.

Comment: Launch your avd from the command line/terminal then and see if that outputs anything. You can also try a smaller RAM size again, but I'd say something else is going on now.

Comment: @A--C Would you know how to launch the avd from the command line?

Comment: This: `emulator -avd 2.2`

Comment: I ended up somehow getting it to work - if you would like to post this as an answer, I would be happy to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting an issue such as

> Failed to allocate memory: 8

This usually means the AVD can't get enough memory to fully operate. A good first step is to open up the ADV Manager, and edit your AVD so it uses less RAM. My configuration is 512MB, but understandably, this will vary with machine, starting from 256MB and working up is a good idea.

[image: AVD RAM]

If now, it still fails, run your emulator from a command line / terminal using

```
emulator -avd -yourAVDName
```

And see if any logs are produced. Then if any are, you have a more concrete cause as to why the AVD is not working and can do more sleuthing.

Answer (score 0):

This problem with memory happens because on Windows the emulator runs as a 32-bit process so it only gets 2GB of user memory which, apparently, is not enough to support both large memory AND large screen.

I solved this problem for myself by marking my emulator-arm.exe as largeaddressaware, which increases available memory to 3GB.

This can be done using editbin.exe which is available as part of Visual Studio.

```
editbin /largeaddressaware <path-to-android-sdk>\tools\emulator-arm.exe
```

The exe is not signed so it won't complain outright. Nevertheless, use it at your own risk, since it's just a hack and can introduce problems if the application is not actually prepared to handle addresses over 2GB limit correctly.

As for me, this was the only way I could run android-17 (4.2) with WXGA800 resolution, otherwise even reducing the memory to 256MB did not work.

BTW, the change is easy to revert, just run the following command:

```
editbin /largeaddressaware:no <path-to-android-sdk>\tools\emulator-arm.exe
```